# how to use Sqlite in windows phone application?

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-7

I have Sqlite install on my system with visual studio 2012 ultimate.Now,I don't have knowledge to how it can be use with windows phone app for saving data and retrieving data from database?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: I use this to develop android apps using SQLite http://xamarin.com/

Comment: use nuget to get the package and then visit sqlite web, there quite a lot sample code there.

Comment: Try to visit http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_use_SQLite_in_Windows_Phone

Comment: Before posting any question here at least try to search in google first. @Akash

Comment: @Rezoan: I try it but i can't understood.can you tell me how it works for windows phone application

Comment: Try to follow the instruction there and if it does not work then in which circumstances you facing the problem ask here with specific code sample. then stackoverflow guys can suggest you the solution of your problem. i think they are not here to teach how to write a windows phone application. Matt Lacey gave some nice link about sqlite integration with windows phone. you should better see those link and come up with your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some posts to get you started:

[A New SQLite Wrapper for Windows Phone 8 and Windows 8 – The Basics](http://t.co/lyNqUseF10)
[SQLite with a bit of MVVM Light in Windows Phone 8](http://t.co/KhCqPDMy)
[Using the SQLite database engine with Windows Phone 8 apps](http://t.co/ZEaTYbxZSj)
[Windows Phone 8 SQLite cross platform sample](http://t.co/aPgEZbul)
[Some great SQLite for Windows Phone posts](http://t.co/jwprr8h0Go)
[Using a simple ORM with sqlite on WP7](http://t.co/7BxA2qw)

Comment: Thanks Matt Lacey I found solution